# Try Catch does not catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm working with code I did not write that uses Entity Framework, which is still a bit of a mystery. In a web api controller there is the code below.

```
try
{
    sdf = sdf.sdf(sdf);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

GetOrderByAlternateIdentifier throws a null pointer exception when a bad orderid comes in. This halts code execution in the GetOrderByAlternateIdentifier method because the error is not trapped. I would think that my try catch above would trap it so I can send back the NotFound response, but it doesn't.

How can I get my try catch to catch the error that occurs in GetOrderByAlternateIdentifier()?

Greg

Comment: Do a web search for "select isn't broken".  Catch is not broken. Something else is going on and you're not telling us about it; that something else explains what you are observing.

Comment: If `GetOrderByAlternateIdentifier` returns an `IEnumerable`, chance are you haven't called the enumerator on it yet. When you do, outside the try-catch you get the exception. Please show more code.

Comment: the error will be occuring in your select or whatever statement inside the method `GetOrderByAlternateIdentifier`  you need to then wrap that in a try catch,  and if it catches,  `throw` the error up through the stack to your current one.    `try catch` only works within your current scope.

Comment: @Nikerym That simply isn't true. If `GetOrderByAlternateIdentifier` doesn't handle an exception, it will remain unhandled until something higher in the stack handles it, or the entire application crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions do not halt code. My best guess at what is happening is that the Visual Studio debugger is breaking when exceptions are thrown. There is a setting that determines whether or not this happens.

However, when you are not debugging, exceptions will not halt the code. And `try...catch` works fine. It's well tested.

Comment: @Johnthan Wood, can you explain why Exceptions do not halt code?  A Runtime Exception would halt your code.  Are you talking in reference to a try/catch block?

Comment: @bdparrish No, a runtime exception (unhandled) would exit the process, exceptions don't make the code halt (as in pause), it makes it halt as in terminate. Code inside catches may halt, but the exception itself does not.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood  Although your correct,  his issue is due to (most likely) not throwing his execption up through the stack from the method he's calling.  Your spot on though,  it's not try catch that has the issue, it's his implementation.

Comment: @Nikerym: That assumes he has a `try...catch` wrapped around the code that is throwing the exception. But if that was the case, it wouldn't "halt" execution. I suppose it could just be improper use of English. If that's the case, then it's hard to know what the heck is going on

Comment: @bdparrish: An exception does not halt code. I can exit the application, but in English halt means to stop. The application does not stop when there's an exception.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood  I would expect he has nothing wrapped around that code,  and it's erroring (hence the halt).   If he put a try catch around it,   he would then need to throw it back up.   `try {whatever} catch { throw exception;}`

Comment: @Nikerym The result of not catching an exception is the same as catching and re-throwing.

Comment: @Preston Guillot your correct,  i got mixed up somewhere. my mistake.

Comment: @Nikerym: What Preston Guillot said.

Comment: @Johnathan Wood - a runtime exception does or does not halt (stop) your code from executing and exit the process?